# framer motion animation based modal causes jittery animations what could be the cause?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, framer-motion

The issue is that for some reason modal doesn't simply open, but instead opens and then repeats the animation, what could be causing this jittery animation repeat?

I control the state using redux global state, the state value (boolean) is set to true and doesn't change, so why does the animation repeat?

```
export default function StarterFormModal() {
  const { user } = useUser();
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const { starterFormModalOpen } = useAppSelector(
    (state) => state.modalState
  );

  const handleClose = () => {
    toast.error('You must complete the form to continue');

  }

  return (
    <AnimatePresence>
      {
        starterFormModalOpen && (

          <Dialog className="fixed inset-0 z-10" onClose={handleClose} open={true}>
            <div className="flex flex-col justify-center h-full pt-4 text-center sm:block sm:p-0">
              <Dialog.Overlay
                as={motion.div}
                initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
                animate={{
                  opacity: 1,
                  transition: { duration: 0.4, ease: [0.36, 0.66, 0.04, 1] }
                }}
                exit={{
                  opacity: 0,
                  transition: { duration: 0.3, ease: [0.36, 0.66, 0.04, 1] }
                }}
                className="fixed inset-0 bg-black/40"
              />

              <motion.div
                initial={{ y: '100%' }}
                animate={{
                  y: 0,
                  transition: { duration: 0.4, ease: [0.36, 0.66, 0.04, 1] }
                }}
                exit={{
                  y: '100%',
                  transition: { duration: 0.3, ease: [0.36, 0.66, 0.04, 1] }
                }}
                className="z-0 flex flex-col w-full h-full bg-white rounded-t-lg shadow-xl max-w-4xl mx-auto overflow-auto"
              >
                {/* <StarterFormComponent /> */}
                <p>Hello world</p>
              </motion.div>
            </div>
          </Dialog>
        )
      }
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
}
```